# On click effect on the image button

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have created image buttons instead of normal buttons.On click on the image button I want a click effect as in the normal icon click effect(On click of menu the background of the icon will be yellow color) of android phones.Using the following code I code show an image on click of the image button .What changes I have to make further.

```
 <item android:state_enabled="true"

 android:state_pressed="true"

       android:drawable="@drawable/production_order" /> 

        android:state_enabled="false"

       android:drawable="@drawable/prodution_orders_icon" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/camera" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/camera" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/camera_active" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I think he just wants an alpha effect, not define a whole new image.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using directly ImageButton you can use Button with customized background

Here is the sample [tutorial](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=56).

Answer (score 0):

create xml file using the button image like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
  android:state_pressed="true" 
  android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
<item 
  android:drawable="@drawable/closebutton" />
</selector>
```

add the color folder in values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
   <color name="yellow">#ffffff00</color>  
</resources>
```